# Keras LSTM time series multi-step predictions has same output for any input

Tags: python, keras, lstm

I have a time series of data that has values that represent 'activity' collected by the minute. I set up an LSTM in order to model the data. The LSTM is set to input 300 points, and output the next 60 points.

I've tweaked the architecture of the LSTM slightly, but the loss usually converges after one epoch and the prediction seems to be the same 60 points for any 300 input.

**Is there anything wrong with my code or general approach?**

```
n_test = int(df.shape[0] * 0.2)
n_in = 300
n_out = 60
n_batch = 1
n_epochs = 3
verbose = 1
neurons = (5,5)

def series_to_supervised(data, n_in=1, n_out=1, dropnan=True):
    n_vars = 1 if type(data) is list else data.shape[1]
    df = pd.DataFrame(data)
    cols, names = list(), list()
    # input sequence (t-n, ... t-1)
    for i in range(n_in, 0, -1):
        cols.append(df.shift(i))
        names += [('var%d(t-%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # forecast sequence (t, t+1, ... t+n)
    for i in range(0, n_out):
        cols.append(df.shift(-i))
        if i == 0:
            names += [('var%d(t)' % (j+1)) for j in range(n_vars)]
        else:
            names += [('var%d(t+%d)' % (j+1, i)) for j in range(n_vars)]
    # put it all together
    agg = pd.concat(cols, axis=1)
    agg.columns = names
    # drop rows with NaN values
    if dropnan:
        agg.dropna(inplace=True)
    return agg

def prepare_data(series, n_test, n_lag, n_seq):
    raw_values = series.values
    raw_values = raw_values.reshape(len(raw_values), 1)
    scaler = MinMaxScaler(feature_range=(-1, 1))
    scaled_values = scaler.fit_transform(raw_values)
    # series_to_supervised is above
    supervised = series_to_supervised(scaled_values, n_lag, n_seq)
    supervised_values = supervised.values
    train, test = supervised_values[0:-n_test], supervised_values[-n_test:]
    return scaler, train, test

scaler, train, test = prepare_data(df, n_test, n_in, n_out)

def fit_lstm(train, test, n_lag, n_seq, n_batch, nb_epoch, n_neurons, verbose):
    # reshape training into [samples, timesteps, features]
    X, y = train[:, :n_lag], train[:, n_lag:]
    X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], 1, X.shape[1])
    X_test, y_test = test[:, :n_lag], test[:, n_lag:]
    X_test = X_test.reshape(X_test.shape[0], 1, X_test.shape[1])
    model = Sequential()
    model.add(LSTM(n_neurons[0], batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), 
                   return_sequences=True, stateful=True, dropout=0.4))
    model.add(LSTM(n_neurons[1], batch_input_shape=(n_batch, X.shape[1], X.shape[2]), stateful=True))
    model.add(Dense(y.shape[1]))
    model.compile(loss='mse', optimizer='adam')
    losses = []
    val_losses = []
    min_val_loss = (99999,999999)
    for i in range(nb_epoch):
        if verbose!=0:
            print(i)
        history = model.fit(X, y, validation_data=(X_test,y_test), epochs=1, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=verbose, shuffle=False)
        losses.append(history.history['loss'])
        val_losses.append(history.history['val_loss'][0])
        if val_losses[-1] < min_val_loss[0]:
            min_val_loss = (val_losses[-1], i)
        model.reset_states()
    print('best val_loss and epoch:',min_val_loss)
    plt.title('loss')
    plt.plot(losses)
    plt.plot(val_losses, color='red')
    plt.show()
    return model

model = fit_lstm(train, test, n_in, n_out, n_batch, n_epochs, neurons, verbose)
# Running on 3 epochs:

# Train on 420005 samples, validate on 105091 samples
# Epoch 1/1
# 420005/420005 [==============================] - 1183s - loss: 0.0143 - val_loss: 0.0086

# Train on 420005 samples, validate on 105091 samples
# Epoch 1/1
# 420005/420005 [==============================] - 1185s - loss: 0.0142 - val_loss: 0.0086

# Train on 420005 samples, validate on 105091 samples
# Epoch 1/1
# 420005/420005 [==============================] - 1179s - loss: 0.0142 - val_loss: 0.0086

def forecast_lstm(model, X, n_batch):
    X = X.reshape(1, 1, len(X))
    model.reset_states()
    forecast = model.predict(X, batch_size=n_batch, verbose=0)
    model.reset_states()
    return [x for x in forecast[0, :]]

def make_forecasts(model, n_batch, points, n_lag, n_seq):
    forecasts = list()
    for i in range(len(points)):
        X = points[i, 0:n_lag]
        forecast = forecast_lstm(model, X, n_batch)
        forecasts.append(forecast)
    return forecasts

forecasts = make_forecasts(model, n_batch, test, n_in, n_out)

def inverse_transform(forecasts, scaler):
    inverted = list()
    for i in range(len(forecasts)):
        forecast = np.array(forecasts[i])
        forecast = forecast.reshape(1, len(forecast))
        inv_scale = scaler.inverse_transform(forecast)
        inv_scale = inv_scale[0, :]
        inverted.append(list(inv_scale))
    return inverted

forecasts = inverse_transform(forecasts, scaler)
actual = inverse_transform(test, scaler)

def evaluate_forecasts(test, forecasts, n_lag, n_seq):
    total_rmse = 0
    if type(test) is list:
        test = np.array(test)
    for i in range(n_seq):
        actual = test[:,(n_lag+i)]
        predicted = [forecast[i] for forecast in forecasts]
        rmse = np.sqrt(mean_squared_error(actual, predicted))
        print('t+%d RMSE: %f' % ((i+1), rmse))
        total_rmse += rmse
    print('total rmse: ', total_rmse)

evaluate_forecasts(actual,forecasts,n_in, n_out)

# t+1 RMSE: 155.838490
# t+2 RMSE: 168.965727
# t+3 RMSE: 167.270456
# t+4 RMSE: 176.760815
# t+5 RMSE: 127.637996
# t+6 RMSE: 186.222487
# t+7 RMSE: 160.867497
# t+8 RMSE: 131.757333
# t+9 RMSE: 171.576859
# t+10 RMSE: 164.078086
# t+11 RMSE: 189.710840
# t+12 RMSE: 135.071027
# t+13 RMSE: 176.108870
# t+14 RMSE: 123.596369
# t+15 RMSE: 176.243116
# t+16 RMSE: 158.860359
# t+17 RMSE: 146.936220
# t+18 RMSE: 146.639956
# t+19 RMSE: 153.618794
# t+20 RMSE: 147.312042
# t+21 RMSE: 149.182079
# t+22 RMSE: 138.054920
# t+23 RMSE: 145.804312
# t+24 RMSE: 166.382771
# t+25 RMSE: 143.922779
# t+26 RMSE: 156.105344
# t+27 RMSE: 115.304277
# t+28 RMSE: 135.514702
# t+29 RMSE: 154.820486
# t+30 RMSE: 188.279115
# t+31 RMSE: 138.019347
# t+32 RMSE: 160.715638
# t+33 RMSE: 173.415381
# t+34 RMSE: 180.411886
# t+35 RMSE: 145.646395
# t+36 RMSE: 128.124628
# t+37 RMSE: 164.583304
# t+38 RMSE: 182.525903
# t+39 RMSE: 145.345988
# t+40 RMSE: 172.166096
# t+41 RMSE: 129.625155
# t+42 RMSE: 137.745757
# t+43 RMSE: 198.990463
# t+44 RMSE: 166.928849
# t+45 RMSE: 171.436070
# t+46 RMSE: 186.811325
# t+47 RMSE: 144.422246
# t+48 RMSE: 156.781829
# t+49 RMSE: 172.120825
# t+50 RMSE: 149.682804
# t+51 RMSE: 141.673213
# t+52 RMSE: 172.357648
# t+53 RMSE: 158.622753
# t+54 RMSE: 184.421916
# t+55 RMSE: 171.320013
# t+56 RMSE: 106.285773
# t+57 RMSE: 114.165503
# t+58 RMSE: 124.827654
# t+59 RMSE: 102.873840
# t+60 RMSE: 134.097910
# total rmse:  9274.59023828

def plot_forecasts(series, test, forecasts, n_in, n_out):
    t = pd.DataFrame(test)
    f = pd.DataFrame(forecasts)
    t.iloc[:,n_in:n_in+n_out] = f.values
    t['idx'] = len(series) + t.index.values - n_in - len(test) -n_out
    # plot the forecasts in red
    for i in range(len(forecasts)):
        xaxis = np.array([t.loc[i,'idx']] * (n_in+n_out)) + np.array(range((n_in+n_out)))
        yaxis = t.iloc[i,:-1].values
        plt.plot(xaxis, yaxis, color='red')
    # plot the entire dataset in blue
    plt.plot(series.values)
    plt.show()

plot_forecasts(train,actual,forecasts[-1],n_in,n_out)
```

Images:
[image]

Above is a plot of the latest prediction (of the test set: need to use 360 points, where the first 300 are the input to the LSTM, and the last 60 will be compared to the forecast shown in red). For any point I put in, that same jagged line at around value 200 is outputted. Here is a zoomed in look using a different 300 points:

[image]

After removing the model.reset_states() in forecast, the RMSEs reduced to and the graph looks different:

```
t+1 RMSE: 56.001612
t+2 RMSE: 55.304949
t+3 RMSE: 54.572932
t+4 RMSE: 53.878164
t+5 RMSE: 53.252430
t+6 RMSE: 52.709159
t+7 RMSE: 52.188684
t+8 RMSE: 51.722300
t+9 RMSE: 51.298685
t+10 RMSE: 50.909361
t+11 RMSE: 50.534432
t+12 RMSE: 50.153235
t+13 RMSE: 49.843989
t+14 RMSE: 49.544826
t+15 RMSE: 49.251911
t+16 RMSE: 48.953321
t+17 RMSE: 48.736308
t+18 RMSE: 48.524235
t+19 RMSE: 48.319380
t+20 RMSE: 48.123144
t+21 RMSE: 47.924274
t+22 RMSE: 47.724813
t+23 RMSE: 47.548941
t+24 RMSE: 47.430078
t+25 RMSE: 47.320304
t+26 RMSE: 47.237417
t+27 RMSE: 47.138287
t+28 RMSE: 47.041020
t+29 RMSE: 46.933505
t+30 RMSE: 46.832966
t+31 RMSE: 46.733669
t+32 RMSE: 46.637092
t+33 RMSE: 46.564030
t+34 RMSE: 46.419809
t+35 RMSE: 46.220688
t+36 RMSE: 46.112665
t+37 RMSE: 46.053153
t+38 RMSE: 45.999633
t+39 RMSE: 45.950166
t+40 RMSE: 45.903748
t+41 RMSE: 45.861863
t+42 RMSE: 45.825802
t+43 RMSE: 45.798098
t+44 RMSE: 45.776262
t+45 RMSE: 45.702105
t+46 RMSE: 45.659707
t+47 RMSE: 45.613096
t+48 RMSE: 45.577615
t+49 RMSE: 45.554801
t+50 RMSE: 45.531822
t+51 RMSE: 45.506663
t+52 RMSE: 45.485158
t+53 RMSE: 45.461476
t+54 RMSE: 45.400751
t+55 RMSE: 45.365654
t+56 RMSE: 45.334558
t+57 RMSE: 45.316315
t+58 RMSE: 45.300184
t+59 RMSE: 45.253731
t+60 RMSE: 45.223637
total rmse:  2870.0986146
```

Images:
[image: no reset 24 hours]
[image: no reset 6 hours]

Edit: Adding in a few more points and the output. The same 60 points are being output for any 300 input.

[image: sample300_1]
[image: sample300_2]
[image: sample300_3]

Comment: Could you provide `forecast_lstm` function?

Comment: edited, thanks for catching that.

Comment: Why are you resetting model states? This makes `LSTM` memory useless. Moreover - `predict` method also resets states.

Comment: I will rerun the predictions without the reset_states and post an update here. I originally did not have the reset_states, but then as I ran the same set of 300 points multiple times through, it would come out with slightly different 60 points, and eventually converge to some number. I was not sure if predict was actually resetting the states, and also thought something about stateful=True was affecting things.

Comment: Results should be the same. But let's check it.

Comment: And - what is a result?

Comment: You're right, it does not give a different result for different points. However, it still gives a 60 point output that is the same for any 300 point input. Added 3 more images to show this.

Comment: Try [this](https://keras.io/models/model/#predict_on_batch) function: `forecast = model.predict_on_batch(X)`.

Comment: Looks like predict_on_batch(X) also outputs the same for the test set (total rmse:  2869.95692901), and also outputs the same 60 points for any 300.

Comment: I am trying now to do X = X.reshape(X.shape[0], X.shape[1], 1) while training. I believe for Keras this means [0] sets of 1-featured [1] timestamps of data. Do you think that will make any difference? It is going much slower to train.

Comment: Are you just feeding the network 200 or so examples and expecting it to predict a complex trend perfectly? I think you are overestimating the ability of the LSTM, I think you would be better served predicting just the next point given the previous 300. You should expect an increase in error the further into the future you predict

Comment: Yeah 300 to get 60. I wouldn't expect "perfectly", but maybe a pattern of some sort. Each of those datapoints represents a value at a single minute, and it tends to follow a work hours, where activity is 0 for  a few hours span at some points. Would adding more lag features/adding more timesteps/increasing network complexity help at all?